# Access redux store in react test

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-testing-library

I have the following test

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import  {store}  from '../../app/store';
import Game from './Game';

test('should render Game component correctly', () => {
  const { getByText } = render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Game/>
    </Provider>
  );   

});
```

I would like to make some assertions about the Game component based on the state in the redux store, but how do I access the state from within my test?

Comment: If you dispatch some actions in your component, after mutating the state, you can get the whole state using `store.getState()`.  Need more details to explain what do you want to test

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your tests in a `describe` function, like so:

```
let store;
describe("Your test", () => {
  test('should render Game component correctly', async () => {
    const { getByText } = render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Game />
      </Provider>
    );
    await findByText('This text is now visible because your state was updated by the reducer');
  });
});
```

Inside, add a `beforeEach` statement above your tests:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    store = createTestStore();
});
```

Implement your `createTestStore` function:

```
export function createTestStore() {
  const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
      // The reducers you use
      example: exampleReducer,
    })
  );
  return store;
}
```

I wrote this answer based on an article by Phil Lucks in Medium. Here is a [link](https://medium.com/@lucksp_22012/dont-use-mock-store-use-your-real-store-b319d7e4e22e) if you want to check it yourself!

Comment: But how do I access the state of my store in the test?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Redux, but isn't the state held inside the store? According to the docs, `createStore` generates the store with the initial state, reducers mutate it, and you can retrieve it by using `store.getState()`